# Find the minimum numbers of Students in class to be sure that 3 of them are born in same month.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Find the minimum numbers of students in class to be sure that 3 of them are born in same month.

Can anybody provide me the solution and make me clear about it!

Comment: This is related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

You can start by considering some numbers. If there are 12 students, is it possible that all of the are born in different monts? How about 13? 14? 15? 16? ...

Comment: What is the worst case scenario?  What happens if you then add one more student?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose n=12 (pigeon holes)

k+1= 3
i.e k=2

Now the number of pigeons be k.n+1
i.e k.n+1= 2*12+1 =25

Comment: When you are not sure, you should include your attempt in the question rather than answering the question.  In fact, the expectation on this site is that you include your attempt in the question itself.  That said, $25$ is correct since the worst case scenario is that the class has two students born in each month, so adding an additional student ensures that you will have at least one month with at least three students born in that month.

Comment: ok next time  iwill include my attempt in the question!!!